# Get menu and sub menu JSON data from txt file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently getting data from a text file and printing the data into my HTML file. This is my code:

```
$.get('assets/test.txt', function(data) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var headerText = jsonData["header"];
    var title = jsonData["title"];
    var body = jsonData["body"];
    var footer = jsonData["footer"];

    $("h1").text(headerText);
    $("h2").text(title);
    $("#main-copy").html(body);
    $("#footer-wrapper p").html(footer); 
});
```

However I need to get the data from a menu and submenu within the .txt file and wrap them into a `<ul></ul>` so that the final menu would look like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="subpage1.html">SubPage 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="subpage2.html">SubPage 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
```

This is the data from the .txt file:

```
{
    "header": "This is me doing a test",
    "menu": [{
        "title":"Home","url":"index.html"
        }, {
            "title":"Page 1",
            "url":"page2.html"
        },{
            "title":"Page 2",
            "url":"page2.html",
            "submenu": [{
                "title":"SubPage 1",
                "url":"subpage1.html"
            },{
                "title":"SubPage 2",
                "url":"subpage2.html"
            }]
        },{
            "title":"Contact",
            "url":"contact.html"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Welcome to our homepage",
    "body": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra sit amet ante at commodo. Sed tincidunt rhoncus fermentum. Donec fermentum volutpat est, a interdum odio scelerisque non. Nullam facilisis magna ac ipsum sollicitudin accumsan. Sed id dui adipiscing, condimentum magna non, molestie ipsum. Donec varius massa eget justo vulputate rhoncus. Integer laoreet turpis id magna rutrum sodales. Nullam eu mauris hendrerit, vulputate nisi ut, condimentum metus. Donec eros ligula, facilisis ac mi a, accumsan vestibulum tortor. Morbi tellus felis, tempor non mi ac, viverra porta lorem. Phasellus dignissim, mauris id vulputate malesuada, tortor metus placerat justo, bibendum vehicula velit magna in leo. Sed condimentum tortor ac ipsum ultricies, quis tristique massa malesuada. Vivamus vitae congue felis. Etiam dictum aliquet felis. Sed euismod in sem eu semper. Nam pulvinar nisl nisi, venenatis bibendum leo lobortis vel.<\/p><p>Nulla pharetra odio non leo sollicitudin, vel semper lorem sagittis. Pellentesque viverra pulvinar elementum. Donec pulvinar consequat augue. Aenean vitae libero sit amet quam faucibus pulvinar ac sit amet nibh. Fusce venenatis magna nulla. Curabitur dignissim justo eu purus pharetra suscipit. Donec tempus eros eget cursus vestibulum.<\/p>",
    "footer": "Copyright &copy; 2019"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy implementation for two level menu.

```
//iterating menu 
jsonData['menu'].forEach((element, index) => {
  var e = '<li><a href="'+element.url+'">'+element.title+'</a>';

    //check if has own property
    if(element.hasOwnProperty('submenu')){
      e += '<ul>';
      element['submenu'].forEach((el, i)=>{
          e += '<li><a href="'+el.url+'">'+el.title+'</a></li>';
      })
      e += '</ul>';
    }
   e += '</li>';

  //append prepared data
  $('#menu').append(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a `function` will create an `<ul>` if you will provide you `menu`to function. I used `recursion` and `forEach`. I used pure js you can convert it into `jQuery`

```js
const menu = [{
        "title":"Home",
  "url":"index.html"
        }, {
            "title":"Page 1",
            "url":"page2.html"
        },{
            "title":"Page 2",
            "url":"page2.html",
            "submenu": [{
                "title":"SubPage 1",
                "url":"subpage1.html"
            },{
                "title":"SubPage 2",
                "url":"subpage2.html"
            }]
        },{
            "title":"Contact",
            "url":"contact.html"
        }
    ]

function createUl(arr,ulClass = "menu"){
 const ul = document.createElement('ul')
 ul.className = ulClass;
 arr.forEach((item) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.className = "nav-link";
  a.href = item.url;
  a.innerHTML = item.title;
  li.className = "nav-item";
  li.appendChild(a);
  //checks if item has submenu
  if(item.submenu){
                        //passing 'sub-menu' as 'ulClass' because this will be nested 
   li.appendChild(createUl(item.submenu,"sub-menu"));
  }
  ul.appendChild(li)
 })
 return ul;
}
document.body.appendChild(createUl(menu))
```